# Forcing mouse movement along specific axis in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How can I force the mouse to move along a specific axis while the user keeps the left button down?
I would like the user to be able to move the mouse along the X axis while any movement on the Y axis would be "canceled".

thanks
Eden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/9b07abce-bb32-4cd1-9ae5-d34973d5cc95

From the link:

```
public partial class MouseOperations 
{ 
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]   
    [return:System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]    
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y); 
}
```

You'll have to call the method from the [Mouse.MouseMove event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventhandler.aspx).

```
MouseOperations.SetCursorPos(xAxisPosition,0);
```